# Cannot link to index.js(main page) of next.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

There are the next.js app that I have implement.

Some how when I create a component with `<ButtonGroup>` and use the `<Button href="index">Home</Button>` to give these a button a link to return to homepage (index.js) from other pages.

But it cannot link back when click the button. And this error is coming up `404 | This page could not be found` .

The `index.js` is in the same folder called 'pages' with the other files like `inventory.js`, `sale.js`, `totalSale.js` and etc.

I also try it with `<NavBar>` and `<Link>` as well. But, it still does not work.

I also call and import `ButtonBar()` to other pages(.js files) as well.

This is my code:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap/DropdownButton';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import ButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup';

export default function ButtonBar() {
    return (
      <ButtonGroup>
        <Button href="/index">Home</Button>
        <Button href="/inventory">Inventory</Button>
        <Button href="/sale">Sale</Button>

        <DropdownButton as={ButtonGroup} title="Account" id="bg-nested-dropdown">
            <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1" href="/totalSale">Total Sale</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2" href="/balance">Account Balance</Dropdown.Item>
        </DropdownButton>

        <DropdownButton as={ButtonGroup} title="Notification" id="bg-nested-dropdown">
            <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1" href="/needItem">Need Item</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2" href="/stock">Stock</Dropdown.Item>
        </DropdownButton>

      </ButtonGroup>
   );
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

To navigate, you need to import `Link` from `next/link`

```
import Link from 'next/link'
```

use it like this

```html
<Link href="/">
    <Button>Home</Button>
</Link>
<Link href="/inventory">
    <Button>Inventory"</Button>
</Link>
```

You can refer next doc [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)